# Setting audio file media metadata in Android (ID3)

Tags: android, audio, metadata, media, id3

I am trying to find out if there is a way to set media metadata (mainly ID3 such as artist, album, song, ...) on an anudio file in Android.

I have noticed that it is possible to retrieve such information using [MediaMetadataRetriever](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html) but cannot find out a way to set it.

Can you please help? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [DataStorage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) to get a File-Object from the MP3-File you want to edit and then use a [ID3-Tag Library](http://www.id3.org/Implementations) like [Jaudiotagger](http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/) to edit the ID3-Tags.

Comment: Well, I actually found the resource as well and was looking at the code. But thanks. Flagged it as answer.

Comment: Do you know perhaps about other audio files formats? I need to know about reading&modifying metadata of supported files formats that can be recorded. I've written about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36473337/878126

Answer (score 0):

From the CLI, you can use [id3ed](http://freshmeat.net/projects/id3ed/). Just build it using Android's NDK, then you can use adb debug bridge to access the shell.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use a third party library

http://jid3.blinkenlights.org/

http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/