# how to add metadata to my recording e.g. artist, album, year etc in android

Tags: java, android

this code is used to save a recording, how do I add metadata to my recording that are saved in a directory in Android, or is there any way to do it at the time of creating the recording

```
*mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 10) {
        mRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(96000);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
    } else {
        // older version of Android, use crappy sounding voice codec
        mRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(8000);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(12200);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    }*
```

Comment: You add metadata to the file. After it is created.

Comment: Possible Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017747/setting-audio-file-media-metadata-in-android-id3